# Are there any repositories for Magento1 patched version

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, core-hacks

Are there any github repositories for magento code patched with all the latest patches.

Basically, I would like to identify the core changes made to Magento 1.7.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror

Comment: Is it patched version of magento?